# MySQL - add column to table and insert "tag" if order is from new customer

Tags: mysql

I have simple table:

```
Order_ID  Client_ID   Date         Order_Status
1         1           01/01/2015   3
2         2           05/01/2015   3
3         1           06/01/2015   3
4         2           10/01/2015   3
5         1           12/01/2015   4
6         1           05/02/2015   3
```

I want to identify orders from new customers which are orders in same month in which that customer made first order with Order_Status = 3

So the output table should look like this:

```
Order_ID  Client_ID   Date         Order_Status  Order_from_new_customer
1         1           01/01/2015   3             yes
2         2           05/01/2015   3             yes
3         1           06/01/2015   3             yes
4         2           10/01/2015   3             yes
5         1           12/01/2015   4             NULL
6         1           05/02/2015   3             no
```

I wasn't able to successfully figure out the query. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Why are rows 3 and 4 "yes"? And why is row 5 NULL instead of "no"?

Comment: Because there is Order_Status = 4. yes/no should be count/applied only where Order_Status = 3

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement along with a `SELF JOIN` like below

```
select t1.*,
case when t1.Order_Status = 3 and MONTH(t1.`date`) = 1 then 'yes' 
when t1.Order_Status = 3 and MONTH(t1.`date`) <> 1 then 'no'
else null end as Order_from_new_customer
from order_table t1 join order_table t2 
on t1.Order_ID < t2.Order_ID
and t1.Client_ID = t2.Client_ID;
```

Comment: How does that detect if it's the same month as the first order by the customer?

Comment: @Barmar, missed that point, now it will. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Now you're just testing if the month is January, not the first month that the customer made an order.

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that gets the date of the first order by each customer.

```
SELECT o.*, IF(MONTH(o.date) = MONTH(f.date) AND YEAR(o.date) = YEAR(f.date),
               'yes', 'no') AS order_from_new_customer
FROM orders AS o
JOIN (SELECT Client_ID, MIN(date) AS date
      FROM orders
      WHERE Order_Status = 3
      GROUP BY Client_ID) AS f
ON o.Client_ID = f.Client_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `order` table gets big, the solutions from Rahul and Barmar will tend to get slow.

I would hope your shop *will* get many orders and you *will* run into performance trouble ;-). So I would suggest marking the very first order of a new customer with a tinyint column, and when you have the comfort of a tinyint, you could code it like:

```
0 : unknown
1 : very first order
2 : order in first month
3 : order in "grown-up" mode.
```

The very first order you could probably mark easily, everyone loves a bright new customer enough to store this event somehow during first ordering. The other orders you can identify in a background job / cronjob by there "0" for unknown, or you mark your old customers and store the "3" on their orders.

Answer (score 0):

The result-set can be achieved without any table-join or subquery:

```
select
if(Order_Status<>3,null,if(@first_date:=if(@prev_client_id!=Client_ID,month(date),@first_date)=month(date),"yes","no")) as Order_from_new_customer
,Order_ID,Client_ID,date,Order_Status,@prev_client_id:=client_id 
from
   t1,
   (select @prev_client_id:="",@first_date:="")t
order by Client_ID ,date
```

One extra column added for computation and `order by` clause is used.

Verify result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c29f/24